# Por que no me reconoce esta variable global Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero **simular** el almacenamiento de una base de datos creando una clase TS en la que almacenar un array de un objeto creado.

Mi problema reside en que cuando intento acceder a la porpiedad **PERSONAJES** de mi constante me da error, como si no lo encontrara:

A continuacion muestro como lo he desarrollado:

**Archivo global.ts**

```
    import { personaje } from "./personaje";

 export const GlobalVariable = Object.freeze({
    
    PERSONAJES:Array<personaje>()  
   
});
```

---

**El componente donde quiero usar el archivo global.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalVariable } from "../../model/global";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-personaje-crear',
  templateUrl: './personaje-crear.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personaje-crear.component.css']
})
export class PersonajeCrearComponent implements OnInit {

  private lista_personajes: GlobalVariable.PERSONAJES;
  
  constructor(
  
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

**Personaje.ts**

```
export class personaje{

    private nombre:string;
    private alias:string;
    private raza:string;
    private edad:number;
    private historia:string;
    private equipaje:string;
    private url_img_perfil:string;

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cómo rellenas el array de personajes? No aportas suficientes datos para dejar claro el problema

Answer (score 0):

Un error que veo que tiene es que esta tratando de declarar private lista_personajes del tipo GlobalVariable.PERSONAJES la cual es una constante mas no una clase

```
private lista_personajes: GlobalVariable.PERSONAJES;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en esta linea solo se esta definiendo el tipo de la variable pero no el valor:
`private lista_personajes: GlobalVariable.PERSONAJES;`

Cuando lo correcto es:

`private lista_personajes = GlobalVariable.PERSONAJES;`

No es necesario definir el tipo en este caso dado que la variable es definida con un valor al momento de la declaración por ende Typescript puede deducir el tipo de la variable